# `/var/log/syslog` grew to a very large size

Tags: filesystem, nvidia-driver

I have faced this problem many times, where `/var/log/syslog` grew to a very large size, which made my elementary os black screen because the filesystem was full, I have found a [solution to this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/dxpysi/filesystemfull/), but I have not found what is the cause.

can anyone help me explain why `var/log/syslog` can have a very large size?

this is the log.

```
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fb9d402a790] vdpau_chroma filter error: video mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
```

Comment: can you add your syslog in your question?

Comment: @LinkPhoenix  can't enter the GUI, in my case the size of `/var/log/syslog` is up to 90 GB. This problem occurs several times after sleep (lock-mode) within a few hours.

Comment: @HasaneSurvayama some answer is to delete the log and reboot but it is not a solution. Maybe you can do `cat /var/log/syslog` in recover mode and give use the output for analyse your `syslog`

Comment: @LinkPhoenix I will that on do the same problem later, because I am sure I will face the same problem, because this time I have already deleted my /var/log/syslog, but is it possible to read a large file (cat)? or is there another way? –

Comment: `tail n50 /var/log/syslog` will show only the last 50 lines of the file. If you want another number of lines, just change the number.  If you wish the output to be not on the screen but in some file you can use `tail n50 /var/log/syslog > filename` instead.  Replace `filename` with the name of the file you want to create, you can choose any name.extension you want, I recommend the extension to be txt. Without sharing this information, no one can guess what is filling your syslog file with so much information.

Comment: @LinkPhoenix I have updated the log. and I found a similar problem 
 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[i dont know what is producing the gigabytes of error in syslog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561565/i-dont-know-what-is-producing-the-gigabytes-of-error-in-syslog/585714#585714)
is a similar question.

I have posted details on a bug [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585714/137608). It is related to VLC (and perhaps other video players).
The bug was not solved. But as a way to stop the output, closing VLC apparently works. As per messages in the bug thread, and my own experience, avoiding having a playing video while switching users, and perhaps workspaces, should prevent the issue from appearing. Starting VLC at the command line is an alternative workaround, since all output would go to stdout.

Comment: Yes, I do that, I'm sure it's an easy way to avoid problems. but somehow the error like this does not happen again, is there an update on the Nvidia driver or other updates I also don't know. but if the problem occurs I usually do truncate on `var/log/syslog`