# full disk problem

Tags: disk-management, disk

I'm on elementary OS 6.1 and I recently tried to download csgo to test out performance compared to windows, I had Left 4 dead 2 installed before that and during the download I realized there wasn't enough space so i stopped the download and extended the partition size.

Anyway, the download said there was no disk space when it was at 50% with more than enough space so I deleted the download files and restarted the download. After that I was just chilling on my computer and I checked my disk and it was full to the dot, it said "0 bytes left" and I was confused to why this happened. I tried looking for the csgo files thinking maybe they didnt get deleted after uninstlling the game, but there weren't any files.

I restarted my computer thinking it could resolve the issue but I got locked out of the desktop so I moved some files through a live boot to access it and now I don't know what to do.

Edit: here's something weird I found when I was checking the properties of each file in the file system:

[image]

Comment: I found out what was happening the log file got clogged up and i cleared it, space is all good now!

Comment: maybe it can help https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/var-log-syslog-grew-to-a-very-large-size